# API de Google Calendar devuleve null en colorId

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar

Desarrollé un script usando la API de Google Calendar para PHP que recupera los datos del evento de una cuenta comercial administrada con GSUITE, recupera prácticamente todos los datos excepto el colorID y el creator->displayName que los entrega en nulo.

Probé esta misma secuencia de comandos con mi cuenta personal de gmail y me recupera absolutamente todo.

¿Qué debería considerar en este caso?

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar al menos el código que no funciona para probarlo? Gracias. Ten en cuenta que GSuite cambió hace poco el Calendario, quizá haya cambiado algo en la API, habría que verificarlo... Puedes probar a usar **`backgroundColor`** o bien **`foregroundColor`** en lugar de `colorID`a ver si funciona. [La doc dice esto](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList): *... **`colorID`** This property is superseded by the **`backgroundColor`** and **`foregroundColor`** properties and can be ignored when using these properties.*

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero me refiero a los datos del evento y no los del calendario https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events y como digo probé este mismo script con otro service account pero de mi cuenta personal de gmail y todo corre bien, pero con la cuenta GSUITE me devuelve los datos pero el colorID del evento en null al igual que el displayName del creator del evento.

Comment: Muestra el código que estás usando. La **[documentación indica de hacerlo así para PHP](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/colors/get)** : `// Print available event colors.
foreach ($colors->getEvent() as $key => $color) {
  print "colorId : {$key}\n";
  print "  Background: {$color->getBackground()}\n";
  print "  Foreground: {$color->getForeground()}\n";
}`. ¿Lo estás haciendo así y no funciona?

Comment: Sucede que de esa manera se obtienen los posibles colores que la API define para poder asignar a un evento el momento de crearlo, la manera de obtener el color asignado a un evento ya creado es: foreach ($events->getItems() as $event) {
      $endTime = new DateTime($event->getEnd()->getDateTime());
      echo $event->getSummary() ." [".$event->getColorId()."] (".$endTime->format('Y-m-d').")<br>";
    } [referencia](https://blog.kodono.info/wordpress/2016/04/18/get-color_id-from-a-google-calendar-using-api-php/)

Comment: ¿No habrás dejado camino real por vereda? Yo te estoy mostrando los enlaces a la documentación oficial de Google y ellos dicen que ese es el método para obtener los colores de cualquier evento creado. No dice que sea para asignar colores a un evento: ***Colors: get**: Returns the color definitions for calendars and events.* Actualiza tu librería a la última versión, la de Google, y prueba como ellos te dicen, puede que el enlace que muestras esté basado en viejas versiones de la API. Me parece que Google sabe más de su API que el autor del post que refieres.

Comment: De todos modos, si estás obteniendo bien tus eventos, haz un `var_dump($events)`  y observa lo que hay dentro... allí podrás ver quizá con qué clave viene el `colorId`.

Comment: Mira acá están los métodos de la [documentación oficial](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Calendar_Event.html#_getColorId), tengo la librería actualizada. y acá le puedes ver una referencia más de la [documentación oficial](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/calendar/model/Event.html#getColorId())

Comment: le hice el var_dump($events) y me retorna un null con la cuenta de GSUITE, pero con una cuenta ordinaria de gmail, el mismo script me devuelve una cadena con el valor del ID que es un 5 si es amarillo, un 11 si es rojo, [según esta tabla](https://github.com/egeldenhuys/csv-to-calendar)

Comment: ¿En la cuenta de G-Suite tú tienes activada la API de Calendar en la [Consola de Proyectos de Google](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis)?

Comment: Si la tengo activada tanto en la cuenta personal de gmail como desde la cuenta de administración del dominio GSUITE, con permisos de propietario sobre el proyecto en ambos casos. GSUITE y gmail.